# Removing u' from result of cursor.fetchall()

Tags: python, unicode, jaydebeapi

I'm using python 2.7 with `jaydebeapi` and `informix jdbc driver (ifxjdbc.jar)` to execute a select on a table and all the fields have `u'some_text'`
Here's my code

```
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("SELECT * FROM table1")
res = curs.fetchall()
print res
```

using

```
res_final=[str(x) for x in res[0]]
print res_final
```

converts the first line in the result correctly. Any idea how can I convert all the selected rows? I had the same problem with sqlite3 but adding

```
conn.text_factory=str
```

solved my problem. I can't find something that works in the same way for `jaydebeapi.`

Comment: Why do you need to convert to bytestrings **at all**? The `u''` prefix is just a *type indicator*.

Comment: I was trying to pass the rows resulting from the select to a combobox in PyQT and also in a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutely need to encode Unicode values to bytestrings, try to do so *as late as possible*, e.g. when pushing the values somewhere that can only handle bytes, like a file or network socket.

You can encode all columns in all rows with a nested list comprehension:

```
res = [col.encode('utf8') if isinstance(col, unicode) else col for col in row]
       for row in curs.fetchall()]
```

which only encodes values that are actually Unicode strings, in a manner that'll work with all Unicode codepoints.

If however all you are concerned about is the `u''` prefix, then there is *absolutely no need* to encode. Don't confuse a type indicator in container representations for actual data.